# Django admin page not loading

Tags: python, django

i have created my superuser django admin id and after that i run the server.instead of showing admin page it shows[when i put "/admin" it shows this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDh6E.png)

but if i enter some other urls for eg."/shop" it is working [this page is working correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/059lZ.png)

i have tried to search on net for this problem,but cant find out the solutionmy codes are as follows

```
settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'shop.apps.ShopConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
    'onetouch.apps.OnetouchConfig',
]
```

url.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('shop/', include('shop.urls')),
    path('onetouch/', include('onetouch.urls')),
]
```

shop>models.py

```py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.AutoField
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
```

Comment: `product_id` is not defined correctly, you need to create an instance of the field `product_id = models.AutoField()` although I'm not sure that's your error

Comment: Why did you tag this with 3 totally irrelevant tags?

Comment: Do you have any output in the logs for the dev server?

Comment: @lain Shelvington thanks for your reply but its not working even after that

Comment: @ruohola i am new to this community sorry

Comment: @RishabhRai do you get anything in the logs/output from runserver?

Comment: C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\one_touch\mac>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 11, 2020 - 20:00:30
Django version 3.0.2, using settings 'mac.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Not Found: /
[11/Jan/2020 20:00:33] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2132

Comment: i am getting this